# First spiral, then diagonal

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, matrix

Given a positive input number \$n\$, construct a spiral of numbers from \$1\$ to \$n^2\$, with \$1\$ in the top-left, spiraling inward clockwise. Take the sum of the diagonals (if \$n\$ is odd, the middle number \$n^2\$ is counted twice) and output that number.

Example for \$n = 1\$:

```
1

(1) + (1) = 2
```

Example for \$n = 2\$:

```
1 2
4 3

(1+3) + (4+2) = 4 + 6 = 10
```

Example for \$n = 4\$:

```
 1  2  3 4
12 13 14 5
11 16 15 6
10  9  8 7

(1+13+15+7) + (10+16+14+4) = 36 + 44 = 80
```

Example of \$n = 5\$:

```
 1  2  3  4 5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9

(1+17+25+21+9) + (13+23+25+19+5) = 73 + 85 = 158
```

### Further rules and clarifications

- This is [OEIS A059924](http://oeis.org/A059924) and there are some closed-form solutions on that page.
- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can choose to either 0-index or 1-index, as I am here in my examples, for your submission. Please state which you're doing.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 22):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 34 bytes

```r
function(n)(8*n^3-3*n^2+4*n+3)%/%6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1PDQisvzljXGEgaaZto5Wkba6rqq5r9L04sKMip1DC0MjTQSdP8DwA)

The [OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A059924) lists the following formula for `a(n)`:

```r
(16*n^3 - 6*n^2 + 8*n + 3 - 3*(-1)^n)/12
```

However, I skipped right over that to get to the PROG section where the following PARI code is found:

```r
floor((16*n^3 - 6*n^2 + 8*n + 3 - 3*(-1^n))/12))
```

Naturally, `+3-3*(-1^n)` is the same as `+6` so we can simplify the linked formula, first by reducing it to

```r
(16*n^3-6*n^2+8*n+6)/12 -> (8*n^3-3*n^2+4*n+3)/6
```

and using `%/%`, integer division, rather than `/` to eliminate the need for `floor`.

Comment: `+3-3*(-1)^n` is not really same as `6`, although the difference is lost in integer division.

Comment: @fergusq you're right, but the formula given as the expression in PARI (which I base my solution on) has `+3-3*(-1^n)` which is the same as `+6`. I will update my answer to make that more obvious.

Comment: @Giuseppe It's `+6` if `n` is odd, but `+0` when `n` is even

Comment: @Bergi `3-3*(-1^n)` is always `6` but `3-3*(-1)^n` has that alternating behavior. The original formula has the latter, which makes the use of integer division unnecessary, as it is always divisible by 12

Comment: Ah, right. It's weird though that the original author overlooked this, isn't it?

Comment: Congrats on 7k (you had 6,999 before I upvoted)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

Saved some bytes by porting [Giuseppe's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/59487).

```python
lambda n:((8*n-3)*n*n+4*n+3)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBPj4IwEMXvfIrJJCYgZRVRF03Y2173ojcgRqVIExxMW@Lup2fLiuv/Jk2nzZvfvNfDjy4qGjV5lDTler/J1kBz2w775AVOn/rkjs0OnMG0OUhBGjChhdgfSpELnsGSKw2LWmieEFpWXkkQIAjkmnbc9pk/dOYWnDoFQ@8DWW4Lx7L@Yd7NSiihz2/NKXuEbysp@VavJFd1qRVEEI8Y@EMGwZhBaE5/EjIYvZvbODDVdDJlMAvC9NKrDbLtHL70KtSqExvZ3chYeH4KUQR/GbpYuCw4nARgmMhMTqGQKS3tVue4@Aat5ozttKqo6jKDDUf2bAwDPBZiW0DLivEoK9qheey0mMYXp6kZgRbchnSjqyxXH/5V7zdcQpXfGVJz6Cns2a3vG5IJAAOYoXNmXAiCXjNm3nNK8ws)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>36</s>  34 bytes

Saved some *more* bytes thanks to [@LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun).

```python
lambda n:((8*n-3)*n*n+4*n+n%2*3)/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBfb4IwFMXf@RQ3NzEBLFNAHZqwt73uRd@AGJUiTfBi2hK3T8/KZPPPtEnT2@bc3z2nxy9d1hS0RZy21eawzTdAC9uOXPJCxyWXhhOzaRC4oTOatUcpSAOmtBSHYyUKwXNYcaVh2QjNU0LLKmoJAgSB3NCe2z7zx87CgnOnYOi9ISts4VjWH8y7WSml9P6pOeX/4btaSr7Ta8lVU2kFMSQBA3/MIJwwiMzpTyMGwau5TUJTzaYzBvMwyi692iC7zvFTr0Kte7GR3Y1MhOdnEMfwk6GPhauSw1kAhonM5BQKmdLS7nTOEF@g0/xie60q66bKYcuRPRrDAE@l2JXQsRI8yZr2aB57LWbJxWlmRqAFtyGH8VWWqw//aA5bLqEu7gypBQwUDuzO9w3JBIARzNH5ZVwIgp4z5t5jSvsN)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBfb4IwFMXf@RQ3NzEBLFNQGZqwt73uRd@AGJUiTfBi2hK3T8/KZPPPtEnT2@bc3z2nxy9d1hS0RZy21eawzTdAC9v2Q5e80HHJpWFkNg0CN3RGftAepSANmNJSHI6VKATPYcWVhmUjNE8JLauoJQgQBHJDe277zB87CwvOnYKh94assIVjWX8w72allNL7p@aU/4fvain5Tq8lV02lFcSQBAz8MYPJlEFkTn8WMQhezW06MVU4CxnMJ1F26dUG2XWOn3oVat2LjexuZCI8P4M4hp8MfSxclRzOAjBMZCanUMiUlnanc4b4Ap3mF9trVVk3VQ5bjuzRGAZ4KsWuhI6V4EnWtEfz2GsxSy5OMzMCLbgNOYyvslx9@Edz2HIJdXFnSC1goHBgd75vSCYAjGCOzi/jQhD0nDH3HlPabw)

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBfb4IwFMXf@RQ3NzEBLFNAHZqwt73uRd@AGJUiTfBi2hK3T8/KZPPPtEnT2@bc3z2nxy9d1hS0RZy21eawzTdAC9uOXPJCxyWXhhOzaRC4oTOatUcpSAOmtBSHYyUKwXNYcaVh2QjNU0LLKmoJAgSB3NCe2z7zx87CgnOnYOi9ISts4VjWH8y7WSml9P6pOeX/4btaSr7Ta8lVU2kFMSQBA3/MIJwwiMzpTyMGwau5TUJTzaYzBvMwyi692iC7zvFTr0Kte7GR3Y1MhOdnEMfwk6GPhauSw1kAhonM5BQKmdLS7nTOEF@g0/xie60q66bKYcuRPRrDAE@l2JXQsRI8yZr2aB57LWbJxWlmRqAFtyGH8VWWqw//aA5bLqEu7gypBQwUDuzO9w3JBIARzNH5ZVwIgp4z5t5jSvsN)

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks and Thanks.

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBPj4IwEMXvfIrJJCYgZRVRF03Y2173ojcgRqVIExxMW@Lup2fLiuv/Jk2nzZvfvNfDjy4qGjV5lDTler/J1kBz2w775AVOn/rkjs0OnMG0OUhBGjChhdgfSpELnsGSKw2LWmieEFpWXkkQIAjkmnbc9pk/dOYWnDoFQ@8DWW4Lx7L@Yd7NSiihz2/NKXuEbysp@VavJFd1qRVEEI8Y@EMGwZhBaE5/EjIYvZvbODDVdDJlMAvC9NKrDbLtHL70KtSqExvZ3chYeH4KUQR/GbpYuCw4nARgmMhMTqGQKS3tVue4@Aat5ozttKqo6jKDDUf2bAwDPBZiW0DLivEoK9qheey0mMYXp6kZgRbchnSjqyxXH/5V7zdcQpXfGVJz6Cns2a3vG5IJAAOYoXNmXAiCXjNm3nNK8ws) credits to Giuseppe for approach

Comment: @LeakyNun I was updating with that too

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
((8#-3)#*#+4#+3)/6&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfQ8NCWddYU1lLWdtEWdtYU99M7X9AUWZeiYJDWrRpLNf//wA)

Saved some bytes by porting Giuseppe's approach.

## Mathematica, 58 bytes

I always enjoy questions with given answers
thanx to oeis (for the nice question and answer)

```
LinearRecurrence[{3,-2,-2,3,-1},{0,2,10,34,80},2#][[#+1]]&
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be golfier to use the closed form?

Comment: many answers are using my simplification, so you may as well do the same

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
((8#-3)#*#+4#+3)/6&
```

You can run it with the following syntax:

```
((8#-3)#*#+4#+3)/6&[5]
```

Where `5` can be replaced with the input.

You can [Try it in the Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/113ae9b9-ff6e-4bd8-88ef-9b73efaa30bd) (Copy-Paste + Evaluate Cells)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.

```
⁽ø\DN2¦ḅ:6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4oG9w7hcRE4ywqbhuIU6Nv/It8OH4oKs/w)

Comment: `8,-3,4,3` -> `⁽ø\DN2¦` to save one byte

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>25</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
8*3-**4.*+3+6÷
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=OCozLSoqNC4qKzMrNiVGNw__,inputs=NA__)

Translation of [Mr.Xcoder's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141075/59183) which is using [Giuseppe's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/59183). SOGL's not winning anything here :p

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
tt2^Qw6Y3YL-wXytP+*ss
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6TEKC6w3CzSONJHtzyisiRAW6u4@P9/UwA)

Comment: You can shorten a bit with [`UQG1YL-tP,wXds]+`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzTQ3TDSR7ckQKc8IqU4Vvv/f1MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 33 bytes

```
I:u8**.../\*3t3n*3t+u@O,6+3+t3*4p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/TqtRCS0tPT08/Rsu4xDgPSGiXOvjrmGkba5cYa5kU/P9vDAA)

cube version:

```
      I : u
      8 * *
      . . .
/ \ * 3 t 3 n * 3 t + u
@ O , 6 + 3 + t 3 * 4 p
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Implements the same algorithm as my [R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/67312). I suspect this can be golfed down.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

Uses the same base-conversion technique as [Leaky Nun's Jelly submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141079/53748)

<sup><s>Maybe</s> there is a shorter way to create the list of coefficients<s>?</s></sup>

-1 byte thanks to Datboi (use spaces ans wrap to beat compression(!))

```
8 3(4 3)¹β6÷
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQsFYw0TBWPPQznObzA5v///fBAA)**

#### How?

```
8 3(4 3)¹β6÷               stack: []
8            - literal            ['8']
  3          - literal            ['8','3']
   (         - negate             ['8',-3]
    4        - literal            ['8',-3,'4']
      3      - literal            ['8',-3,'4','3']
       )     - wrap               [['8',-3,'4','3']]
        ¹    - 1st input (e.g. 4) [['8',-3,'4','3'], 4]
         β   - base conversion    [483]
          6  - literal six        [483,6]
           ÷ - integer division   [80]
             - print TOS           80
```

---

My 13s...

```
•VŠ•S3(1ǝ¹β6÷
```

```
•2ùë•₂в3-¹β6÷
```

```
•мå•12в3-¹β6÷
```

All using compressions to find the list of coefficients.

Comment: `8 3(4 3)¹β6÷` to safe 1 byte (no fancy compression though)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 24 bytes

```java
n->((8*n-3)*n*n+4*n+3)/6
```

Port of [*@Giuseppe*'s R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/52210).
Note that `/6` floors by default when calculating with integers in Java.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LU7LDoIwELzzFXtsIWAMakwQ/0AuHI2HWqopwpbQQmIM316XR7Kzm92dyUwtRhGbTmFdfbxshLVwExp/AYBGp/qXkAqKeV0OINnckWd0mQhU1gmnJRSAkIPH@MrYOcQ45SGGGB0IKd@dfLayu@HZEHsTjUZX0JIhK12v8X1/gOCr28v0i5fO9xnoSw5HGlG0fQHKr3WqTczgko6krkGGCcXjS7Y13RRM/g8)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

Saved 5 bytes using [Giuseppe's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/59487).

```
=INT((8*A1^3-3*A1^2+4*A1+3)/6)
```

---

First attempt:

```
=(8*A1^3-3*A1^2+4*A1+3*MOD(A1,2))/6
```

Evolved from a direct implementation of formula from OEIS (37 bytes):

```
=(16*A1^3-6*A1^2+8*A1+3-3*(-1)^A1)/12
```

`+3-3*(-1)^A1` logic can be changed to `6*MOD(A1,2)`.

```
=(16*A1^3-6*A1^2+8*A1+6*MOD(A1,2))/12
```

Does not save bytes, but allows removal of a common factor for 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 17 bytes

```
/+3+*^Q2-*8Q3*4Q6
```

**[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%2B3%2B%2a%5EQ2-%2a8Q3%2a4Q6&input=5&debug=0)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 14 bytes

```
8*3-**Q4*+3+6f
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=8%2a3-%2a%2aQ4%2a%2B3%2B6f&input=5&warnings=0&hex=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
8*3-**4I*+3+6÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fQstYV0vLxFNL21jb7PD2//9NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
[DcKI]6/iZQk
```

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=%5BDcKI%5D6%2FiZQk&inputs=5&version=20.4.1)

#### Explanation

Same approach as [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141076/36398).

```
[DcKI]   % Push array [8, -3, 4, 3]
6/       % Divide each entry by 6
i        % Push input
ZQ       % Evaluate polynomial
k        % Round down. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 14 bytes

```
8×3⁻××@4×+3+6/
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3@LwdONHjbsPTz883cHk8HRtY20z/f//TQE)**